# Can a Pinion bike work with an indoor direct drive trainer?

Tags: internally-geared-hub, trainer, belt-drive, gates

I have a Priority 600 bike with a pinion c.12 gearbox and a Gates belt drive, and I'm currently contemplating winter training plans.  Will this work with a Tacx NEO 2T trainer, provided that I buy a gates freewheel cog to fit where the cassette is supposed to go?

Comment: For instance, would this hub be compatible with this trainer?  https://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=74263

Comment: Hm, if I had a gearbox+belt bike I'd ride it _outside_, enjoying the absence of a derailleur system being ruined by the winter conditions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I do bike around a lot in the winter, especially on weekends, but during the week, it gets dark before work ends, so any trip that I make after work is solely utilitarian, because I don't really enjoy biking in both the cold and dark, so I needed to find some way to exercise on weekdays during the winter, and I'm hoping this is it.

Answer (score 5):

No, sadly that hub won't be compatible with the trainer.  Your trainer expects a cassette of 9-11 or 12 speeds, which presumes a chain.

Full specs are at https://www.garmin.com/en-US/p/701670#specs

That hub you listed clearly has a thread on the inside, so is for a freewheel.  In the text it says "for thread-on freewheel hub"

[image]

---

I believe you're going to need a rear cog for your type of drive belt, that matches the splines on your trainer's freehub.

https://www.gatescarbondrive.com/products/rear-sprockets?product_line=CDX could be a good place to start.

---

Your other option is to get a cheap chain-based bike and permanently mount that on your trainer.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make this work, you will need a HG (shimano) spline Gates sprocket of the correct type for your belt, a singlespeed conversion sprocket kit with lots of thin spacers and also be confident adjusting the beltline properly to match the Pinion (using the spacer kit).

You will also need to be confident adjusting the belt tension as I have found it changes between different wheels, possibly due to axle dimensions or other component tolerances.

My top tip is to install a normal chain sprocket on the trainer hub so that you can use a normal chainwhip to undo the lockring in the future. Locate it so that it won't interfere with your belt. If you don't do this you will need to have the gates whip or make your own with an old belt whn you want/need to disassemble.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Would I need the gates whip to install the sprocket on the trainer, or is that only necessary for taking it on and off the bike?

Comment: You only need the whip for disassembly (sprocket removal) to hold the freewheel mechanism against your turning force. When you are tightening things up, you are working against the resistance of the wheel etc, as you are when riding. @kloddant

Answer (score 0):

I have been advised separately that I need 2 things: a new sprocket and cassette spacers.

Cassette Spacers:

https://surlybikes.com/parts/spacer_kit

Sprocket Options:

https://www.gatescarbondrive.com/products/rear-sprockets/28t-9-spline-cdx
https://www.gatescarbondrive.com/products/rear-sprockets/28t-9-spline-cdx-sl

I am going to talk with my local bike shop about these as well.  If I try this out and get this to work successfully, I'll mark it down here for future reference.

Comment: The surly kit should give you enough adjustment. It's worth remembering that the gates sprocket is quite thick so some more of the thinner spacers might help you to get it just right. Many bike shops have these individually.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the sprocket is normal or an SL, the CDX SL is lighter and cheaper while the CDX is heavier but more durable.